# R - midnight POSIXct to date

Tags: r, posixct, as.date

If I have midnight (or even around midnight posixct) date like this

```
> as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00:00")
[1] "2020-01-01 CET"
```

But if I transfer it to the date I get one day before this date

```
> as.Date(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00:00"))
[1] "2019-12-31"
```

In case that hour is lets say 8am etc, as.Date works properly. How can I get 2020-01-01 date for my example where hour is midnight?

Comment: `as.Date(substr(x, 1, 10))` should also work

Comment: If `ct` is your POSIXct object try `as.Date(format(ct))`  That will format it using your default time zone and then as.Date will get the date for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the timezone again.

As you can see in `?as.Date`:

> ## S3 method for class 'POSIXct'
>
> as.Date(x, tz = "UTC", ...)

The function defaults to UTC.

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00:00",tz="CET"),tz="CET")
#[1] "2020-01-01"

as.Date(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00:00",tz="CET"))
#[1] "2019-12-31"
```